# Why does AFNetworking hangs on first request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am completely baffled on this. Each time I test my app in the simulator or on a real device, it hangs for 30,40,60 seconds on this bit of code, but all following request to this API call will load in milliseconds.

I thought it was related to DNS resolving for the first time, so I switched to an IP address for testing and that did not resolve the issue.

If it's the first request after the app starts, it will just hang for a large amount of time, once it has loaded, you can open the view for the same data set or another and it load the list very fast.

Any recommendations?

```
-(void)getVendorImages {
    //Alloc the image list
    self.imageList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Prepare the request
    NSString* vendorImagesApi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"http://example.com/api/v1/vendor/images/",self.imageData.vendorId];

    NSLog(@"Getting list of images %@",vendorImagesApi);

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:vendorImagesApi
      parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

//             NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

             //Get images
             for (id imageData in responseObject)
             {
                 // prepare image url
                 NSString* imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",@"http://example.com/images/",imageData[@"id"],@"-650x650.jpg"];
                 NSLog(@"Putting this in in a list: %@", imageUrl);

                 [self.imageList addObject:imageUrl];
             }
             [self.tableView reloadData];

         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the thread stack

[image]

Comment: getVendorImages from where is it called

Comment: viewDidLoad "[self getVendorImages];"

Comment: and this is the very first view controller? i mean to say after applicationDidFinishLaunching this view controller viewDidLoad is called

Comment: Nope. I'm doing somewhat a classic UIScrollViewController with images that you can view by scrolling left to right, which is the first view and has a call to the same domain for another api url. Once you tap on one of them images it will open this view, which is a UITableViewController and loads additional images.

Comment: IT's ok that is from UIScrololviewcont.. viewdidload.
"has a call to the same domain for another api url" i think u r talking about imageUrl? And this return you image which you show on tavleview cells ??

Comment: Don't worry about that, it's in another view and is unrelated, I was just pointing out that the app had already called the api before this view. This section of code which is what is hanging, just gets a list from the API and compiles that list of strings into an array. AFNetworking handles loading the images with lazy loading in a cell view.

Comment: Does NSLog (Putting this...) show the same delay as the UI? In any case: you really should consider placing the call to `[self.tableView reloadData];` the on main thread. For example: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self.tableView reloadData];});`

Comment: Yes, it's jamming up right when you call AFHTTPRequestOperationManager till the success, only on the first time the view loads. You can close the view after it loads for the first time, and open it again for the same data point or a new data point and it lighting fast.

Comment: Can you press pause in Xcode debugger when app hanged, expand all threads call stacks and attach screen shots of the thread call stacks to the question?

Comment: Yes. It's been added to the post.

Comment: So I did some more testing. on the view before this view I'm using a self rolled manager to call the API, however as I have gotten better at Objective-C I have started using libraries like AFNetworking. Turns out the first call for AFNetworking is always slow no matter where it's called in the app, but after that point any other url request with AFNetworking will fire quickly even if they are in another view, etc. I'm not sure if that can be fix or if I'm just going to have to rebuild the entry controller to use AFNetworking first the code that I wrote back when I started the project.

Answer (score 1):

So after a bunch of digging, I removed all the files for AFNetworking, then installed it all again, including the UIKit+AFNetworking folder, after that I removed all the frameworks and added back UIKit and SystemConfig. Lastly one of my views that loaded at the start of the app had it's own NSURLConnectionDelegate. I removed all that and had it use AFNetworking, and that did the trick. Apparently the first run that was stalling the connection for AFNetworking was because it was likely fighting over who could use the service.